# When a system has multiple levels of cache memory, why L2 always has more memory than L1?

Tags: caching, memory

When a system has multiple levels of cache memory, \L2 always has more memory than L1. Why is this necessary?

Comment: What good would it do if it was less or the same? Just think about it for a moment.

Comment: So if it was less, the L1 would not be fully utilized when copying data from L2, and if it was the same, they would have the same data and L2 therefore become useless?@SamiKuhmonen

Comment: Exactly. It's completely logical

Comment: thats not 100% correct. If the caches are exclusiv, L2 holds not the same data as L1. So it could work with a smaller L2-cache, however it wouldnt be usefull.